# How to get country border lines while plotting with imshow in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, netcdf, python-xarray, imshow

I am trying to plot seasonal mean from a netcdf file using xarray and matplotlib. I am getting the plots with latitude and longitude axes but there is no country border line. How to obtain country border lines on the plots.

```
import xarray as xr
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fname='/home/atmosphere/data/outputs/2010.nc'         #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

ds=xr.open_mfdataset(fname)
varlist=list(ds.variables)
imr=ds.sel(lat=slice(0,35),lon=slice(60,100)) #subsetting overthe region
imrbt=imr['temp']                             #making into a data array  
ds['time.season']

seasonal=imrbt.groupby('time.season').mean(dim='time')
seasonal.plot.imshow(col='season',robust=True)
```

Comment: Use Cartopy: https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bart mentioned, you have to use `[cartopy][1]` to solve this issue:

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
air = xr.tutorial.open_dataset('air_temperature').air
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Orthographic(-80, 35))
seasonal.plot.contourf(ax=ax, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS)
ax.coastlines()
```

To add country borders in higher resolution you have to use cartopy features:

```
import cartopy.feature as cfeature

country_borders = cfeature.NaturalEarthFeature(
    category='cultural',
    name='admin_0_boundary_lines_land',
    scale='50m',
    facecolor='none')
ax.add_feature(country_borders, edgecolor='gray')
```